# AMP emails ads - 'amp-ad' component is unsupported

Tags: amp-html, amp-email

Our company has AMP page versions of our regular article and news pages. We are using the `amp-ad` component to display ads on those pages.

We also have multiple HTML newsletter products with ad placements.
I'm working on a POC of AMP4EMAIL and documentation is lacking regarding monetization of this. The `amp-ad` tag is not in the list of email components. Is there a valid spec option to display ads?
Is it ok to use AMP `amp-img` / or regular HTML `a` tags for AMP email ads?

It is important for us to comply with the rules to avoid problems with the Google registration process for AMP emails or other future issues.

I tried to use the `amp-ad` tag in the [the email validator](https://validator.ampproject.org/#htmlFormat=AMP4EMAIL) and it failed to validate.
The [email playground](https://playground.amp.dev/?runtime=amp4email) output included same errors but the ad was displayed!

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡4email>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-ad" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-ad-0.1.js"></script>
  <style amp4email-boilerplate>body{visibility:hidden}</style>
</head>
<body>
  <amp-ad data-loading-strategy="1" data-slot="/6001/sek.amp/amp_5" height="250"
          json='{"targeting":{"d":["news","sectors"],"t":["earnings","transcripts","has-audio","us","asset-management","financial","article"],"aid":"4256772","a":"sa-transcripts","cnt":["19","3","4","15","21","6","12","8","27","36","1","oil","14","fed1","etrfin","fed","taxes","fidelity_retirement","4152537","bny","ssga1","ssga2","ssga3","ssga6","191","jh1","fnk1","fnk2","port","nw1","fr1","fnk3","fnk4","loan","NYL1"],"prstock":"true","tickerbundle":["growth","value","dividend","large-cap","financials","zacks"],"pr":"amp","s":"amp"}}'
          type="doubleclick" width="300"></amp-ad>
</body>
</html>
```

The validator outputs 2 errors:

- `Custom JavaScript is not allowed.` - regarding the `amp-ad` script in head.
- `The tag 'amp-ad' is disallowed.`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about monetization and not a technical problem.

Comment: I think StackOverflow is not a good place to ask this kind of question - monetization of emails depends on your business model. That said, everything allowed in regular emails is allowed in AMP as well and nothing in Gmail's documentation suggests otherwise I believe. Whatever model you use to monetize your existing emails should be applicable to AMP powered emails as well.

Comment: I didn't ask this as business question but as a technical question. I'll try to rephrase - `amp-ad` is not supported. Is it ok to display regular ads in an amp email using `amp-img` and html anchor tags?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand the issue. If this is something that works in non-AMP HTML emails, I don't see why it wouldn't work in AMP emails?

Answer (score 0):

AMP-email is different from AMP-html.
There is no 'amp-ad' component in AMP-email, so it is not supported there.
Here is a list of all available components in AMP-email: https://amp.dev/documentation/components/?format=email

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this AMP Email code example will help - https://www.plumrocket.com/blog/2019/09/how-to-create-and-test-amp-for-email/ ? You can implement a banner slider similar to the one displayed in live preview. 
`Amp-ad` components are not supported in AMP Emails. Here is the list of all supported AMP Email Components - https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/email/amp-email-components.md